# Xamarin Page Navigation Issue

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, navigation

I'm new to Xamarin, this is my first project from scratch

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
    }
```

This is in `App.xaml.cs`

`LoginPage` has two buttons, each bound to a Command in the same ViewModel, one of which is the following Command:

```
 public Command ShowPopup
        {
            get => new Command(() =>
             {
                 PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new UATSelectionPopup());
             });
            set
            {

            }
        }
```

I'm using a nuget package/library called `Rg.Plugins.Popup` to render a popup on the screen. The popup has two buttons, one of which does this:

`await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Driver.Index(), false);`

I click on the button, which *should* execute the above line of code as far as I understand, but instead the following Unhandled Exception surfaces:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000016 from >typeref (expected class 'Xamarin.Forms.NavigableElement' in assembly > 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null')

It seems the issue occurs before that line of code is even hit. I tried putting a breakpoint on it.

I have Googled around for at least a couple of hours and I'm no closer to understanding the origin of it.

I'm also seeing this, simultaneously:
[image]

I'd like help with:
1) Knowing what's going on, what's causing this exception in easier terms?
2) What is a reasonable solution to this problem?

I appreciate any help; thank you in advance.

**EDIT 04:55AM**
Based on SushiHangover's comment, I read a little about XAMLC and have tried to incorporate it in my project.

I read that it fits well into AssemblyInfo.cs because it's more comprehensive than class-level compilation.

So I added the following lines of code to `Android\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

Nothing seems to have changed. I was expecting some XAML errors.
On a side note, I updated some packages and cleaned up all other warnings. Still no difference. I build fine with no errors or warnings.

Comment: Looks like a malformed XAML file. Turn on the XAML compiler (if it is not) and see if that catches any problems: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc

Comment: Thanks for your comment, please see my edit?

Comment: Wait... it's working now, somehow... I think the updates did something.